# Add a caution over 18

Tags: javascript, html, blogs

I have an adult blog and I was wondering if there's a code  I can put on my blog to do something like a caution asking if you're over 18 or leave the blog now, something like what you see if you go [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/hottestnsfwpics)

I wish I could manage the transparency of the warning...

Answer (score 0):

You can use several different languages to achieve this effect like jquery, javascript, and php.  The link below can help you get started on reading up on how it can be done with some good informational tips:
[Age Verification](http://www.techerator.com/2010/09/how-to-perform-age-verification-with-jquery-and-cookies-mmm-cookies/)

Hope this helps you get started

Comment: jQuery is not a language it's a javascript library.

Comment: Can I use this with a "blog" ? I can only modify the HTML code, I can't create pages...@Ryan Beaulieu

Comment: I guess it depends on the type of blog your using. Are you using something like Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

That's enough to set **NSFW** (not safe for work) label turn on in your Tumblr blog settings:
[image]

Comment: I know that option but even if that, the last time the banned my account so...@Vladimir Starkov

Comment: So maybe [Content Warning Session Cookie](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=188434)